# how to sleep in MPI

Tags: c++, c, process, mpi

I'm building a C program using MPI, simulating some traffic lights. I need for each process to wait for a few seconds then send a message to the other traffic light (process) to change. If I use Sleep(), the program crashes. Is there a safe way to make a process sleep for a given number of seconds?

Comment: I don't see why your program should crash from using `Sleep()`. Could you post some code?

Comment: It doesn't really crash. What I basically want is to run the MPI program continuosly but if I put everything in a `while` it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post a simplified, reproducible, example of what you are trying to do ?

Comment: You said `Sleep()`; did you mean `sleep()`? (Remember that C identifiers are case sensitive.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate your own sleep() function by using `MPI_WTIME()` and manually waiting for the amount of time you need. Depending on how you're executing (number of cores, nodes, etc.) this might not have any performance hit and gives you the added benefit of being able to do something else while you're waiting for the next light cycle.